# Getting all content inside a DIV including the tag values of input selectors

Tags: jquery

I am loading an html form inside of a container div.  This html is a template that is retrieved from a data base.  The use then fills out the form (or parts of the form).

once the user is done, they select a button that calls a function.

```
function submitForm() {
    var workflowID = $('#workFlowID').val();
    var formID = $('#formID').val();
    var uploadedFiles = $('#uploadedFiles').val();
    var htm = $('#formContent').html();
    console.log(htm);
    alert(workflowID + ", " + formID + ", " + uploadedFiles + ", : " + htm);
}
```

the problem is that I get the form faithfully reproduced, but the input fields are not included in the resulting "htm" I need to be able to reproduce the html as it has been filled in to save to a new table.  What am I missing, or is this even possible?

having been asked for additional information; here is an example the html might have 10 input areas.  Once the appropriate inputs are filled out the form is saved for someone else to look at and add there piece.  When the form is filled out however the reference code above pulls back the html minus the values that were input by the user.

Comment: Please help us out with more information....

Comment: If the form is from the db, why not just save the template's pk and the selected values?  You can recreate it from that information without duplicating what's already in your db.

Comment: The forms are simple forms but have up to 70 input fields.  I originally was going to go this route and still may need to.  But the form maybe used multiple times and the dataf ields then would see the potential of 1 million rows in the course of a year, while the forms themselves are generally less than 16k.  The storage would be minimal and finding the form would be quicker that finding the form sorting through a million records then populating the form.  While the storage would be slightly more by storing the form in a specific table that handles only that request for that form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer the concept is to go through each tag and set the attribute.

```
$("input").each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':text')) { $(this).attr("value", $(this).val()); }
    else if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');

        }
        if ($(this).is("textarea")) {
                $(this).text($(this).val());
        }
        if ($(this).is(':radio')) {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeAttr('checked');

            }

        }
```

then I can go back and do what I was attempting to do to begin with:

```
 var htm = $('#formContent').html();
```

This will include the values entered in the html.

Thanks for all that responded and helped to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to comment on your post like the others but what language are you using server side to facilitate this? Is it C#, PHP or...

Edit:

I think I had a similar problem before. What I did was an AJAX request for the ENTIRE page (all the html elements and everything). You will get this data back in a variable. You have to parse through this variable for the information you are looking for. For example if you want everything just between  and  you can do some string parsing to get that seperate.

I am not saying this is a good thing to do but it might be a viable solution IF I understand correctly.

You might also be able to try 
http://api.jquery.com/html/
and use that on the ID of your form or body.

Comment: The backend is C# WEb Methods, the front end is jQuery, the problem is I would like to simply get the html with the input values.  Saving, storing all that is easy.  The problem is getting the html with the input values intact.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a div within a form element called "formContent" and you want to extract the value (which will likely be html) of all inputs within that div, but the number of inputs is unknown at submit time?  Are they all textareas?

try using jQuery to find all appropriate areas, but I'm not sure what to do with the values.

```
var value = "";
$("#formContent").children("textarea").each(function(){value += $(this).val()});
```

**EDIT:  Adding more after discussion with OP**

So I would add a database table with at least two columns : ElementID and Value.  Make a webservice that checks for the existence of ElementID.  If it exists, update value, otherwise, insert.

Use this data to populate the values of the form when built.  This could be a challenge server-side, you might have to rely on several calls on the client to grab and populate.

Lastly, after the user clicks submit, use a similar approach I showed above to find all inputs and perform an ajax call to the webservice, submitting the element's id and its value.  Something like this:

```
$("#formContent").find("input", "select", "textarea").each(
    function()
    {
        var elementId = $(this).attr("id");
        var value = $(this).val();
        //perform ajax call to webservice with elementId and value parameters
    }
);
```

Keep in mind that every elementId will need to be unique and that this could result in several HTTP requests.  Otherwise, you might want to send some parsable data up to the webservice for all data at once and update accordingly.

Comment: I actually want the html with the inputs intact.  They could be Input, radio, check boxes textareas.  If I have to go back and pull out the values and store those in a separate table then that's what I will have to do.  The hope was is to just save the html whole with the values intact.

Comment: In this case, I'm not really sure you can do that.  Somehow, you are dynamically building the form inputs (is this done serverside or clientside)?  You can get the html of the div that the form is generated in using the .html() property of the formContent selector, however, they will not have "value" attributes applied to them, that is maintained on the DOM, not in the markup.

Comment: Forms are stored in a database table and read into the DIV that I am working with.

Comment: And the form is stored in your database as entire markup, correct?  Including labels, form element ids, etc?

This is an interesting challenge that reaches beyond the simple jQuery portion.  I will update my code above to show what I'm thinking since I only have so many characters in comments  :-P